# Why is Java using more cores than I asked it to?

Tags: java, multithreading, garbage-collection

I have some multithreaded Java code. I know that I spawn three threads. I have six cores, so I expect to see my CPU usage jump between 0% and 50%. However, after adding some new, memory-intensive operations, I'm seeing the CPU usage jump up to 100% -- using all six cores of my machine.

What's going on here? Is this the garbage collector at work?

Comment: You can get a profiler for Java and see for yourself what's running at any given moment. Otherwise, all we can do is guess.

Comment: I have to cores with 2 threads each. I did some calculations in just one thread and saw two of my four threads being at a usage of about 40%. The other cores had a usage of about 1-5%. If your CPU has three cores with two threads each, the JVM is maybee doing the calculations distributed on the physical cores, not the threads in your cores. Just an idea...

Comment: Without some code this is hard to say. For example, since Java 8, the JVM actively tries to process instructions to the new streaming API with as much parallelism as possible. Also, the GC resides in its own thread. As Theodoros already suggested, use a profiler and post its results.

Comment: I'm not sure if I could pull out a small enough region of code to use as an example. I'll try to run it under a profiler and see what's going on. I'm just surprised because as a C programmer, I know that if I spawn three threads, there are going to be at most three CPUs being used. I assume that the other CPU load is some background work the JVM is doing, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: Usually processor utilization is measured in 100% per core. So in your case it would be 600% for full 6 core usage. I think you're looking at wrong property in your utility, so when tasks are light they consume only 50% of each core, when tasks are heavy CPU usage increases by 100% per core.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I profiled and it looks like the spikes in CPU are synchronized with GC collection. This makes sense, since Java 7's default garbage collector [runs in parallel by default](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html).

Answer (score 1):

Its due to many long running threads, You must have to first find out the threads which are running from  a long time.

You can easily find out by taking thread dump.

ps -fL  will give you a list and check LWP respective to time running
jstack  it wil give you hexadecimal value of long running thread

Above PID is java process id.

Hope it will help you to resolve the issue.